# Correct test for measuring pre / post variance for test vs. control

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, anova, t-test

I have a test and control group of URLs, each containing 5,000 URLs, receiving in total roughly similar numbers of visits per day e.g.

**URL | Group | Day | Visits**
URL_1 | Test | Jan 1 | 500 
URL_2 | Ctrl | Jan 1 | 200 
URL_3 | Test | Jan 1 | 100

Or in total:

**Day | Test Visits | Control Visits**
Jan 1 | 50,000 | 60,000 
Jan 2 | 50,500 | 50,000 
Jan 3 | 60,000 | 40,750

**Hypothesis**: A treatment applied to the Test URLs will increase visits to that group.

**Result**: The mean average daily visits to the Test group increased more than the mean average of the Control group in the post-period vs the pre-period (both 30 days).

**Question**: Which statistical test would best confirm that this is, or is not, statistically significant? Specifically:

1. At least;  Are outlier days in pre or post distorting the average variance?
2. Or ideally; Are outlier days, *or* outlier URLs, distorting the average variance?

After much reading and YouTubing I'm pretty confused, I *think* a 2x2 Mixed ANOVA, will at least meet objective 1, but would appreciate some guidance before going down the wrong path.

Thanks!